# SQL parsing in Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, parsing

I'm looking for a SQL parser in Python.

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);

Using the parser, I want to parse only "where condition" and it should print "where condition", another part should be ignored.

Please guide with coding part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem you are describing is a bit unbounded, because a general SQL query might have the `WHERE` keyword appearing multiple times, in subqueries etc.  For a single level select which you give above, you could use:

```
sql = "SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE condition GROUP BY column_name(s) ORDER BY column_name(s);"
where = re.findall(r'WHERE\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\b(?:GROUP BY|HAVING|ORDER BY)\b|$)', sql)
print(where)
```

This prints:

```
condition
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import the `sqlparse` library, but it is only compatible for Python 3.5+.

Here is an example code with what I found:

```
import sqlparse

where = sqlparse.parse('SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE condition GROUP BY column_name(s) ORDER BY column_name(s);')[0]
print(where.tokens)
```

The thing with this is that it doesn't actually parse the thing you're looking for. If you remove `tokens`, it will print the entire thing, but if you leave it this way, it will print the tokens of every sub-string of the string.

See [this page](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#:%7E:text=sqlparse%20is%20a%20non%2Dvalidating,of%20the%20New%20BSD%20license.) for more info.